# My $_SESSION[''] disappears

Tags: php, html, session

Here is my problem, I have a PHP SESSION but it disappears...

That's my code,

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['connect'])) {
        echo $_SESSION['email'];    
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="6;URL=http://www.mywebsite.com/management.php">';
    } 
?>
```

`$_SESSION['connect']` exists, so I pass the If check.

When I display $_SESSION['email'] it works. `$_SESSION['email'] = mymail@gmail.com.`
But when I'm redirected on my page `management.php $_SESSION['email'] = 1.`

management.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['email'];
?>
```

Why?

Thanks.

Comment: are you doing a `session_start()`?

Comment: yes I have a session_start(), I said in my post that "I can display $_SESSION['mail'] and $_SESSION['connect'] test succeed".

Comment: looks good to me. You should be using session_start() on all pages which need access to session. Otherwise it looks like your PHP is broken?

Comment: When your error is in the management.php, why don't you show *that* file to us?

Comment: In management.php, I just try to display my $_SESSION['email'].

Comment: Could you show us some code from management.php ? Look like your session variable is being overwritten on that page somehow

Comment: You do have quotes around the email address in the live code, right?

Comment: management.php published

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this your complete code? if so, you need to add `session_start()` to use sessions.

(see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php )

After question edit: it looks like you have sessoin_start() on this page. But do you have it on the `management.php` page?

Comment: yes I have a session_start(), I said in my post that "I can display $_SESSION['mail'] and $_SESSION['connect'] test succeed".

Comment: Yes. Don't you think that's my meta tag which break my $_SESSION['email'] content?

Comment: Could it be a different (sub) domain? It;s not a different domain, but -guessing here-, if you go to `domain.com/firstpage` that redirects to `www.domain.com/secondpage` (mark the www!) you might get a different session?

Answer (score 2):

are you redirecting accross different domains? If so, you could try to set the name of your session before session_start()

To do that, you have to submit your sessionname via get-parameter in the redirect

`echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="6;URL=http://www.mywebsite.com/management.php?sessionname='. session_name() .'">';`

and then use

```
session_name($_GET['sessionname']);
session_start();
```

in management.php

Answer (score 0):

you must have session_start() on management.php

Comment: duplicate response. not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**set.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

/* prevent XSS. */
$_GET   = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if (isset($_GET['session'])) {
    $_SESSION['session'] = $_GET['session'];
    echo 'set succesfully';
} else {
    echo 'use ?session=<your data> to set session data';
}
```

**get.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

/* prevent XSS. */
$_GET   = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if (isset($_SESSION['session'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['session'];
} else {
    echo 'not set yet';
}
```

**setget.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

/* prevent XSS. */
$_GET   = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if (isset($_GET['session'])) {
     $_SESSION['session'] = $_GET['session'];
    header('Location: get.php');
    exit();
} else {
    echo 'use ?session=<your data> to set session data';
}
```

I have these php files(in a single folder) mapped to `http://localhost/stackoverflow/4826773/`

1. `http://localhost/stackoverflow/4826773/set.php?session=test`

   **output:** `set succesfully`
2. `http://localhost/stackoverflow/4826773/get.php`

   **output:** `test`
3. `http://localhost/stackoverflow/4826773/setget.php?session=hello`

   **output:** `hello`

This is what you want right? If you get different results then something is broken!

**P.S**: I think using

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="6;URL=http://www.mywebsite.com/management.php">
```

is not consider a best practice.